# nginx restrict directory access by ip

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx and want to restrict access to a directory to everyone except myself.  I want to access the php scripts in /restricted.  I've tried a few things so far.  If I recall, this works to block access to all except the allowed ip, but all scripts are pushed to download instead of processed now.

`location ~ /restricted {
  allow 1.2.3.4;
  deny all;
}`

Comment: pushed to download? could you explain a bit further?

Comment: The .php file in /restricted is downloaded rather than parsed as php.  I may have to create a @block to pass the .php in /restricted.

Comment: if /restricted is taking precedence over your "*.php$" handler block, your scripts will act like normal files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need a second (I prefer nested) php block since you want these php files handled differently.  Also, assuming that /restricted is supposed to be a uri prefix and not just something that appears anywhere in the uri, you want a different type of location:

```
# This handles everything that starts with /restricted,
# and no regex locations will override it
location ^~ /restricted {
  allow 1.2.3.4;
  deny all;

  # This will inherit the allow/deny from the outer location
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass backend;
  }
}
```